# NullPointerException on getSystemService() when checking network connectivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am getting error NullPointerException when I check connectivity to the internet in one fragment but in  other fragment it is working perfectly fine.

```
public static boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
            Injection.provideZiauddinAppInstance()
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Apparently `provideZiauddinAppInstance()` is null

Comment: Apparently, the Context you use is dead. What does `provideZiauddinAppInstance()` return, which context?

Comment: it is working fine with other fragments it is mvp structure return from injection class getting context from Application class
if use Context it gives error on getsystemService() (Non static method cannot be referenced from static context)
moreover there is no option for getApplicationContext.

Comment: have you debug on exactly what point you are getting null pointer exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a class ConnectivityReceiver :

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver {

    public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Activity activity) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
    }
}
```

Then use Like this any where you want :

```
if (ConnectivityReceiver.isNetworkConnected(this)) {
//do your things
}
```

Comment: this absolutely worked for me

Comment: then please upvote the answer so that other can also find if they want it

Comment: how to finish the answer? stackoverflow already block my limit of asking questions.

Comment: finish the answer?? what do you meant by this?

Comment: How can I lock this questiona as a complete